# Volume Control - UI Slider for http straming file using AVFoundation, MPMovieController

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, avfoundation, xcode4.5, uislider, avplayer

I'm new to ios development. I've started developing a simple radio app with play/pause and volume control.

Using X Code 4.5

Initially I've used `AVFoundation,AVPlayer & MPMoviePlayerController` to stream http radio 
[ .m3u internet link. ]

Managed to get play & pause working with above mentioned framework / .h files.

I have been running into issues having volume control with`(UISlider)`, no matter what ever frame work I use from above.

Play/Pause/Volume Control with`(UISlider)` works good with physical file such as mp3 etc.

I'm experiencing issue ONLY with HTTP Stream / file - URL reference..

Can some one please assist me as to HOW can I have `UISlider(VolumeControl)` get working?

Any suggestions, advise much appreciated.

PS: I don't want to use Web View as it is an radio app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MPVolumeView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for volume control.

For example:

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:mpVolumeViewParentView.bounds];
[mpVolumeViewParentView addSubview: volumeView];
```